# Вывод связанных таблиц в один DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Программно создаю 2 таблицы, пытаюсь их связать и вывести в один DataGridView, чтобы дочерние записи раскрывались через "плюсик".

```
        dsTests = new System.Data.DataSet();

        DataTable dtQuestions = dsTests.Tables.Add("Questions");
        DataColumn dсQuestID = dtQuestions.Columns.Add("questID", typeof(Int32));
        dсQuestID.Unique = true;
        DataColumn dcQuestion = dtQuestions.Columns.Add("question");
        DataColumn dcQuestType = dtQuestions.Columns.Add("questType", typeof(Int32));

        DataTable dtVariants = dsTests.Tables.Add("Variants");
        DataColumn dcID = dtVariants.Columns.Add("id", typeof(Int32));
        dcID.Unique = true;
        dcID.AutoIncrement = true;
        DataColumn dcVariantQuestID = dtVariants.Columns.Add("questID", typeof(Int32));
        DataColumn dcVariant = dtVariants.Columns.Add("variant");
        DataColumn dcIsRight = dtVariants.Columns.Add("isRight", typeof(Boolean));

        DataRow myRow1 = dtQuestions.NewRow();
        myRow1["questID"] = 1;
        myRow1["question"] = "Сколько будет 5+5?";
        myRow1["questType"] = 1;
        dtQuestions.Rows.Add(myRow1);

        DataRow myRow2 = dtVariants.NewRow();
        myRow2[0] = 1;
        myRow2[1] = 1;
        myRow2[2] = 10;
        myRow2[3] = true;
        dtVariants.Rows.Add(myRow2);

        DataRow myRow3 = dtVariants.NewRow();
        myRow3.ItemArray = new object[] { 2, 1, 5, false };
        dtVariants.Rows.Add(myRow3);

        DataRelation dataRelation = new DataRelation("QuestionsVariants", dсQuestID, dcVariantQuestID);
        dsTests.Relations.Add(dataRelation);

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dsTests.DefaultViewManager;
        dataGridView1.DataMember = "Questions";
```

Не могу понять, в чем у меня ошибка, сейчас в грид попадают записи только из таблицы Questions

Comment: `.DataMember = "Questions";` - что задано, то и отображается

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov в таком случае у меня выводятся только записи из таблицы Questions

Comment: _чтобы дочерние записи раскрывались через "плюсик"_ - стандартный DataGridView не имеет такой возможности, насколько я знаю

Comment: [Master/Detail](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/create-a-master-detail-form-using-two-datagridviews)